# Receiving a 'Bad Request (400)' on PUT request from AWS S3 when a user is trying to upload a song to my rails 6 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm upgrading my rails 5 app to rails 6. During this update, I updated my aws-sdk from v1 to v3. I have included the `aws-sdk-s3` gem in my gemfile as mentioned in the documentation.

One of the main features of my app is allowing users to upload songs. When I've tried to manually test this feature I've encountered the following error:

```
PUT https://bucketname.s3.amazonaws.com/ 400 (Bad Request)
```

Here is the attached XML:

```
<Error>
   <Code>AccessDenied</Code>
   <Message>Access Denied</Message>
   <RequestId>request id code</RequestId>  
   <HostId>host id code</HostId>
</Error>
```

I was trying to check how to solve it in this [S3 documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/ErrorResponses.html) but there I found another confusing detail. While my console returned a 400 status code, 'AccessDenied' is actually written as 403 status code in the documentation.

I'm attaching the Upload model. The commented out lines are the original lines of code I had. I changed it according to what was mentioned on the S3 documentation.

```
class Upload
  attr_reader :filename
  # New lines of code: ####################################################
  require 'aws-sdk-s3'

  Aws.config.update({
    region: 'us-east-1',
    credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id), Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :secret_access_key)),
  })
  #########################################################################
  def initialize(filename)
    @filename = filename
  end

  def url
    #@url ||= bucket_file.url_for(:write, content_type: content_type, acl: :public_read).to_s
    @url ||= bucket_file.url().to_s
  end

  def content_type
    @content_type ||= MIME::Types.type_for(filename).first.content_type
  end

  def to_json(*args)
    { url: url, content_type: content_type }.to_json
  end

  private
  
  def bucket_file
    #@bucket_file ||= bucket.object("uploads/#{SecureRandom.uuid}/#{filename}")
    @bucket_file ||= bucket.presigned_post(key: "uploads/#{SecureRandom.uuid}/${filename}", success_action_status: '201', acl: 'public_read', content_type: content_type)
  end

  def bucket
    #@bucket ||= AWS::S3.new.buckets(ENV['S3_BUCKET_NAME'])  
    @bucket ||= Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: 'us-east-1').bucket(Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :bucket))  
  end

end
```

It is important to mention that I made sure that the credentials are accessible and valid.

Comment: Have you tried doing it with aws cli?

Comment: I need this feature to be accessible for the users. Do you mean debugging it with the CLI?

Comment: Yes. Trying it with the CLI will tell if the problem is in your code or in your bucket configuration.

Comment: Alright, I'll try doing it right now. Thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `url_for` function is deprecated and therefore had to be change to `public_url`.

This is a working version of my original code:

```
class Upload
  attr_reader :filename
  require 'aws-sdk-s3'

  Aws.config.update({
    region: 'us-east-1',
    credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :access_key_id), Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :secret_access_key)),
  })

  def initialize(filename)
    @filename = filename
  end

  def url
    @url ||= bucket_file.public_url().to_s
  end

  def content_type
    @content_type ||= MIME::Types.type_for(filename).first.content_type
  end

  def to_json(*args)
    { url: url, content_type: content_type }.to_json
  end

  private
  
  def bucket_file
    @bucket_file ||= bucket.object("uploads/#{SecureRandom.uuid}/${filename}")
  end

  def bucket 
    @bucket ||= Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: 'us-east-1').bucket(Rails.application.credentials.dig(:aws, :bucket))  
  end

end
```

Answer (score 1):

Dealt with a similar problem as you described.

Note that despite the fact that you fixed up this problem, you will need to make further adjustment before moving to production environment as production env enforces a more thight csrf token regulations.

There is a further explanation here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/archive-RESTObjectPUT.html